# RoR: Method to return a statement in a json format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for a method that will return this statement in a JSON format.

```
def statement
   total = 0
   bonus points = 0
   result = 'Car rental for #{@name.to_s}\n'
    for r in @rentals
      this_amount = 0
      case r.car.style
      when Car::SUV
          this_amount += r.days_rented * 30
      when Car::HATCHBACK 
          this_amount += 15
      if r.days_rented > 3
          this_amount += (r.days_rented - 3) * 15
      end
      when Car::SALOON
          this_amount += 20
      if r.days_rented > 2
          this_amount += (r.days_rented - 2) * 15
      end
      else
    end

        if this_amount < 0
            bonus_points -= 10
        end

        bonus_points = bonus_points + 1
        if r.car.style == Car::SUV && r.days_rented > 1
            bonus_points = bonus_points + 1
        end

        result += r.car.title.to_s + "," + this_amount.to_s + "\n"
        total += this_amount
    end

    result += "Amount owed is " + "#{total.to_s}" + "\n"
    result +="Earned bonus points: " + bonus_points.to_s
    result
end
```

What method would I need to add to my class to return this statement in a JSON format? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do that

```rb
return {:result => result}
```

at the end of your method.

But if you are using controller to show data to user, I would prefer using `.to_json` in my controller method

Comment: Thanks. I have this method in my model. Should it be in the controller in your opinion? Syntax here would be def json_statement return {:result => result} end ? Would that work? It's syntax i'm getting use to, thanks.

Comment: Its kind of general mess really. You need to separate between the business logic of calculating the the bonus or whatever you're doing and how you want to present / serialize it. Right now it really just belongs in refactoring.

Comment: You can call this model method from controller. Have business logic in model method, and prepare the response there and return it to controller. Then from controller you can render a json response like this: `render json: { result: response }`